# Bmw E65 CAS/DME SYNC

Tags: electronics, flash-programing

I have a 2005 BMW with a N52B30 motor. My CAS (Control module Car Access) was bricked and I brought another one for $700. The problem is that this new CAS has another VIN written to it. My question is how can I easily synchronize the CAS with the DME (Digital Motor Electronics) module? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to expand some of those acronyms so the question is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a dealer or someone with access to equivalent software rewrite the VIN.

There is no way to do this otherwise.